# SQL - Constraint on insert value to be less than existed value in other rows

Tags: sql

I do have a table that looks like:

```
CategoryID | GameNO | Name         | Price
-----------+--------+--------------+-------
     1     |    1   | Zelda        |   10
     1     |    2   | Sonic        |   12
     2     |    1   | Metal Gear   |   21
     2     |    2   | Street Fight |   15
```

Where both `CategoryID` & `GameNo` are a primary key, and `GameNo` is a foreign key to another relation.

I want to alter the table and add constraint that each category game price to not be greater than the double price of any other from the same category?

For instance if I want to do:

```
insert into tableName 
values (1, 3, 'Super Mario', 21);
```

The inserted price for Super Mario 21 is greater than the double price of Zelda which is 10. I want to constraint this to be not accepted?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a trigger after update or after insert.

Answer (score -1):

If there is a front-end you should get the value first and limit what they are allowed to enter and tell them why.

Constraints are really a single row thing. Logic like if state='CA' taxes must be greater than zero.

You didn't say what flavor of SQL you use, so I'll show SQL Server.

In my save stored proc I would have:

```
if ((select max(price) * 2 from tablename where CategoryID = @CategoryID) < @Price)
begin
   -- throw exception or raise error here.
end

insert into tablename ....
```

As a side note, there should be a single ID that is unique in the table for each row. What do you do if you want to change Zelda to category 2?  "Game No = 1" is already taken. And foreign keys work best with a single ID. Last nag, a lot of the new development tools (Entity Framework comes to mind) almost demand a single unique key.